# Why split() and shift() do different results when i use directly and when i use they by a variable

Tags: javascript

im having a little difficult to understand one thing.

suppose we have a **`const text = "little text test"`**

when i use **`console.log(text.split(' '))`**

the console return an array with 3 elements 'little', 'text' and 'test'. Until here its ok

so if i use
**`const test = text.split(' ')`** then **`console.log(test)`**
the console return an array with 2 elements 'text' and 'test' and that isnt manking any sense im my mind

the same happen when i try use shift(), if i use **`log.console(test.shift())`** the console return text and its right, cut the first item in the array and bring me the next

but if i use **`const test2 = test.split(' ')`** then **`log.console(test.shift())`** the console return little but shift() remove the first argument of an array... so why i had little?

code:

```
const text = "little text test";
const test = text.split(' ');
const test2 = test.shift();
console.log(text.split(' '));
console.log(test);
console.log();
console.log(test.shift());
console.log(test2);
```

console:

```
[ 'little', 'text', 'test' ]
[ 'text', 'test' ]

text
little
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? `const test = "little text test".split(' ')` results in `test` being an array with 3 items, not 2. Maybe you forgot that `shift` mutates the array, if you had a `shift` in between?

Comment: ill edit the main message with the code

Comment: Please post that in your question, not in a comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3se9aw7/ your explanation doesn't make sense. text and test resulting in the same, not 3 and 2.

Comment: well im really having that exactly results in my console text is resulting in 'little', 'text' and 'test' when test is resulting in 'text' and 'test'

im testing in visual code, idk if do any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong idea about `shift` method. `Array.prototype.shift()`
 does do the following:

**1. It mutates the array.**

```js
const a = [1,2,3]
a.shift();
console.log(a) // [2,3]
```

**2. It returns shifted element.**

```js
const b = [1,2,3].shift();
console.log(b) // 1
```

So, what you see is natural behavior of JS.

```js
const text = "little text test";
const test = text.split(' ');
const test2 = test.shift(); // this line mutate the test array.
console.log(text.split(' '));
console.log(test);
console.log();
console.log(test.shift());  // this line, too. And it prints shifted one, not the whole elements.
console.log(test2);         // test2 holds 'little' string by line 3.
```

Comment: so, to complete my understading, if i use the shift() method i "stole" the first item of array and bring that to the variable?